# Compiler warning in boost crc.hpp with Visual C++ (error C4244)

Tags: c++, boost

I am using `boost/crc.hpp` version 1.49 for crc calculation in Visual Studio 2013.

When I instantiate a variable of type

```
boost::crc_32_type
```

I get a compiler error

```
Error   7   error C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data    C:\boost_1_49_0_0\boost\crc.hpp 578 1   MyProgram
```

I found this ticket from over 5 years ago:
https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3194

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? Do I have to patch crc.hpp?
My warning level is 4.

Comment: If it's not solved in boost (do you have the latest version installed?), wouldn't a simple cast fix it (provided the value returned fits into an `unsigned char`)?

Comment: @Axel I am stuck with 1.49 due to project dependencies. What should I cast? I am just instantiating a var  of type `crc_32_type`. I am using now `#pragma warning(disable: 4244)
#include <boost/crc.hpp> 
#pragma warning(default: 4244)`

Answer (score 2):

I am simply surpressing the warning now.

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4244)
#include <boost/crc.hpp> 
#pragma warning(default: 4244)
```